# How to Export Data From EXTJS grid as well as grid summary renderer

Tags: extjs, grid, renderer

I want to export EXTJS grid data and its summary render in EXCEL and CSV format. Please help any working example.

Answer (score 0):

Grid generally contains no data, it is used to display data. Data contained in the store, so that you want to export data from the store.

You can try this [Ext.ux.Exporter](https://www.sencha.com/forum/showthread.php?136598-Export-store-to-Excel) (I recommend to read full topic, there are described many errors that may occur).

Although I recommend to generate file on the server, solution will depend of your server-side (I use PHPExcel for example).